# Yii2 trim everything on save

Tags: php, yii2, trim, behavior

Yii2 framework. The idea to create common behavior for common model:

- before Validate trims all fields in model.
- if it's array trim all values in array.

  1. I'm wondered why in Yii2 core doesn't exist such possibility. Or I'm wrong. Am I?
  2. What problems could I face if I trim all fields?

Comment: You could use the `trim` rule, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#trim

Comment: yes but in this case I have to write this rule for each model and for all fields that I want to trim. I want to right it once for all models

Answer (score 11):

You can create a behavior and attach it at your models.

1) Create the behavior `TrimBehavior` in `common/components`.

```
<?php

namespace common\components;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\base\Behavior;

class TrimBehavior extends Behavior
{

    public function events()
    {
        return [
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE => 'beforeValidate',
        ];
    }

    public function beforeValidate($event)
    {
        $attributes = $this->owner->attributes;
        foreach($attributes as $key => $value) { //For all model attributes
            $this->owner->$key = trim($this->owner->$key);
        }
    }
}
```

2) In your models add the following:

```
//...
use common\components\TrimBehavior;
//...

/**
 * Returns a list of behaviors that this component should behave as.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TrimBehavior::className(),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Trimming attributes it depends on business logic. If you really need it then it's ok.

Comment: Yes you are totally right, that was exactly what I was looking for. But what potential problem would I face? is it field will be array or related record, or anythings else.

Comment: You have to check using is_array() or something different according what you need each time.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree.

Comment: The behavior should be in  `components` folder, not `common/components`, and namespace should be `app/components`.

Comment: @drgrujic `common` is used in [yii2-app-advanced template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced). Many people use it. So `common` is common ;-)

Comment: This solution, but a little bit more flexible, can be also found as a composer package: [laxity7/yii2-trim-behavior](https://packagist.org/packages/laxity7/yii2-trim-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

I tried suggested solution by Kostas Mitsarakis using behaviours and found that, while it works, will made some additional problems. I think one should do `trim` already on the `$_POST` data, so add this function to your Controller and all the posted data will be trimmed before getting into your model:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, function (&$val, $index)
    {
        $val = trim($val);
        // maybe also:
        // if(empty($val)) $val = null;
    });
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```