# Yii2: trimming values from form at POST stage

Tags: php, post, yii2

I would like to trim all values POSTed from a form (and preferrably also set blank strings to null) so that when I use `Yii::$app->request->post('somefield')` the value has already been cleaned up. Is that possible? Is there a hook for modifying POST values before they are used by `...request->post()`?

I know there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745747/yii2-trim-everything-on-save) solution but I want to do it even before the values end up in the model...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`trim` validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#trim). It does not actually validate the fields but it trims them:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['myfield', 'trim']
        ];
    }
```

To set blank field to `null`, I would [create a custom validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators) that, once again, it does not validate but, if the field is blank, it sets it to `null`:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['myfield', 'myValidator'],
        ];
    }

    public function myValidator()
    {
        if ($this->myfield == '')
            $this->myfield = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't read my question.I said *before* values end up in the model and are validated there - even when I use `$app->request->post('somefield')`...!

Comment: I know but I think that loading them to make us of those validators is the cleanest solution. It is my suggestion, not the only valid solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any help with Yii. But you could do the following before you call `Yii::$app->request->post('somefield')` or `Yii::$app->request->post()`:

```
$_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);
```

or if you have nested form data:

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST, function (&$val, $index) {
    $val = trim($val);
    // maybe also:
    // if(empty($val)) $val = null;
});
```

If you want this for any posted data you could place the code in a beforeAction handler (in controller, module or application). I don't think that it is a good idea, but as always this depends on your situation.